# Only first button works in forEach tag with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

So I ran into a small problem... I have a forEach tag and in it there is a button. The button is connected to a JS which loads another .JSP file. However it seems that only first button works if I connect the JS to the buttons id `$("#imageshow").click` like so, but if I use `$("button").click` it works fine. Despite being able to make it work I have too many buttons in the .JSP file to use it this way. So I would appreciate you help in this matter :)

The .JSP file:

```
   <c:forEach var="building" items="${buildings}" >
        <button id="imageshow" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value="${building.getBuildingID()}">View</button>
   </c:forEach>
```

This is the JS

```
$("#imageshow").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("value");
    $("#imgas").load("SlideShow.jsp?id=" + id);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` attribute should always have a unique value, which is currently not the case. Try using `class` instead (and querying as `.imageshow`.

Comment: I thought that it was the case. So I was actually thinking about using class instead. Thanks for the help ;) Gonna try it right away.

Comment: Added `class="btn btn-default btn-xs imageshow"` and everything works fine :) The style stays the same and now I don't need to worry about any other buttons :)